# Workbox in Create React App without eject

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, workbox

I'm trying to configure [Workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/) in CRA without eject. Anyone succeeded?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After hours trialing and error I succeeded to have workbox in CRA. Here's how I did:

First,`yarn add -D workbox-build`

Next, create a file called `build-sw.js` in the root folder with:

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const pathmodule = require('path');
const workbox = require('workbox-build');

function build() {
  const cwd = process.cwd();
  const pkgPath = `${cwd}/node_modules/workbox-sw/package.json`;
  const pkg = require(pkgPath);
  const readPath = `${cwd}/node_modules/workbox-sw/${pkg.main}`;
  let data = fs.readFileSync(readPath, 'utf8');
  let path = `${cwd}/build/workbox-sw.js`;
  console.log(`Writing ${path}.`);
  fs.writeFileSync(path, data, 'utf8');
  data = fs.readFileSync(`${readPath}.map`, 'utf8');
  path = `${cwd}/build/${pathmodule.basename(pkg.main)}.map`;
  console.log(`Writing ${path}.`);
  fs.writeFileSync(path, data, 'utf8');

  workbox
    .injectManifest({
      globDirectory: 'build',
      globPatterns: ['**/*.{html,js,css,png,jpg,json}'],
      globIgnores: ['sw-default.js', 'service-worker.js', 'workbox-sw.js'],
      swSrc: './src/sw-template.js',
      swDest: 'build/sw-default.js'
    })
    .then(_ => {
      console.log('Service worker generated.');
    });
}

try {
  build();
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

After that, create a file in `src/sw-template.js`with: 
(Have in mind that in this file is where you have to put your own cache strategy. See [Docs](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/get-started) for more info)

```
workbox.setConfig({
  debug: true
});

workbox.core.setLogLevel(workbox.core.LOG_LEVELS.debug);

workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute([]);

workbox.skipWaiting();
workbox.clientsClaim();

workbox.routing.registerRoute('/', workbox.strategies.networkFirst());
```

Finally, in `src/registerServiceWorker.js` change:

```
-      const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/service-worker.js`;
+      const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/sw-default.js`;
```

And in `package.json` change:

```
-      "build": "react-scripts build && sw-precache --config=sw-precache-config.js'",
+      "build": "react-scripts build && yarn sw",
+      "sw": "node build-sw.js"
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks so much for posting the answer to your own question.  This has helped me a lot.  I needed to remove the single quote after `yarn sw` in the final `package.json` step to make it work.

Comment: from where `workbox` is defined `src/sw-template.js` file?

Answer (score 5):

With the merge of [this PR](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/4169), Create React App 2 now support supports Workbox out of the box, since it now uses **[workbox-webpack-plugins](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-webpack-plugin)** internally.

Take a look at the official docs to learn more: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/making-a-progressive-web-app